# O Que significa TL;DR nas perguntas?

Tags: debate

Estava com algumas dúvidas e encontrei no site as minhas respostas, porém uma coisa me deixou intrigado. O que é o TL;DR que existe em algumas perguntas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Declarações muito longas apresentam um dilema para os editores:
>   simplesmente ignorar o que foi escrito ou gastar tempo lendo. Escrever
>   comentários longos indica que você não se preocupou em organizar e
>   sintetizar seu ponto de vista em um texto de tamanho razoável.
>
> Quando isso acontece, alguns editores indicam como resposta a
>   expressão "tl;dr" (do inglês, too long, didn't read) como forma de
>   protestar o texto que foi apresentado. Eventualmente, a expressão
>   também é utilizada pelo próprio autor para indicar que o texto que
>   será apresentado a seguir é demasiadamente longo, mas que ele está
>   ciente disso.

**fonte:** [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Muito_longo;_n%C3%A3o_li)

Answer (score -4):

TL;DR = Too long; didn't read (Muito longo; não li)

É usada para responder a alguém que escreveu um texto muito longo para explicar ou perguntar alguma coisa que poderia ser explicada em poucas palavras.

Comment: Não acho que é isso que significa

Comment: É isso que significa sim. http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr

Comment: @Renan Ok, mas o que eu vejo aqui e no SOen é que ele é usado no sentido que está escrito no final da página do wikipedia linkada na outra resposta, que diz: "Eventualmente, a expressão também é utilizada pelo próprio autor para indicar que o texto que será apresentado a seguir é demasiadamente longo, mas que ele está ciente disso."

Comment: @Math TL;DR (brincadeira)